# Apache POI - count numbers of rows with a particular value in a column thats supports filter

Tags: excel, filter, count, apache-poi, rows

I am trying to write an excel formula to get the count of rows with a particular value in a column using POI. The count should auto update when we apply a filter. 
For eg: If a column has a value say "Y" or "N", I need to get the count of rows having a "Y" in a particular column. This count should auto update when we apply a filter on any of the columns in the excel.

I tried using,

```
cell1.setCellFormula("COUNTIF(S11:S6768,\"N\")");
```

but COUNTIF doesn't auto-update on filter.

I also tried,

```
cell1.setCellFormula("SUMPRODUCT(--(S11:S6768=\"N\"),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(S11,ROW(S11:S6768)-ROW(S11),0)))+(NOW()*0)");
```

but this shows #VALUE! in the resulting cell instead of the result of the formula. Once I click on edit formula and press enter, then it displays the proper result. Then it starts updating when we filter any of the columns.

I tried `workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true)` but it doesn't help. I get a RuntimeException saying something isn't proper in SUMPRODUCT.

The POI version I am using is 3.9

Does anyone have any idea about any other function that I can use for my requirement or how can I proceed at this stage?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not following the instructions on the website and using the [Formula Evaluator](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) to updated the cached value?

Comment: when I use Formula Evaluator as HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);

It throws following exception,
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid arg type for SUMPRODUCT: (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I had to create templates with the required formulas and append the data to the template to get it working. Formulas evaluate fine on opening the excel and also on filter.